# create wic bitmap render target for a IWicBitmap

Tags: render, wic

I have created a IWicBitmap using data present in memory
using

```
hr=pFactory->CreateBitmapFromMemory(512,512,GUID_WICPixelFormat8bppGray,512,512*512,ptr,&Bitmap1)
```

Now i wanted to draw on bitmap so i m creating bitmaprendertarget

```
hr= m_pDirect2dFactory->CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget(Bitmap1,props,&target);
```

but it does not form a target - it returns an error:

```
-2003292288
```

I m not understanding how to solve it
i have set the properties also

```
D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties();
props.minLevel = D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_DEFAULT;
D2D1_PIXEL_FORMAT pixelFormat = D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN,D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE);
props.pixelFormat=pixelFormat;
```

Answer (score 3):

Came into this error myself. The error code `-2003292288` is in fact `WINCODEC_ERR_UNSUPPORTEDPIXELFORMAT` (0x88982F80). The `CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget` method does not accept all WIC's pixel format.

My experiments on Windows 7 to 11 boxes have shown the method seems to accept the following WIC pixel formats for the original bitmap youwant to create a render target on (no matter what format you specify in the D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES structure). As you see, there is no gray format:

```
8bpp Alpha (GUID_WICPixelFormat8bppAlpha)
 Guid: e6cd0116-eeba-4161-aa85-27dd9fb3a895
 Bits Per Pixel: 8
 Supports Transparency: True
 Numeric Representation: UnsignedInteger
 Channel Count: 1

32bpp BGR (GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGR)
 Guid: 6fddc324-4e03-4bfe-b185-3d77768dc90e
 Bits Per Pixel: 32
 Supports Transparency: False
 Numeric Representation: UnsignedInteger
 Channel Count: 3

32bpp RGB (GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGB)
 (Requires Windows 8 or Windows 7 with Platform Update)
 Guid: d98c6b95-3efe-47d6-bb25-eb1748ab0cf1
 Bits Per Pixel: 32
 Supports Transparency: False
 Numeric Representation: UnsignedInteger
 Channel Count: 3

32bpp pBGRA (GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA)
 Guid: 6fddc324-4e03-4bfe-b185-3d77768dc910
 Bits Per Pixel: 32
 Supports Transparency: True
 Numeric Representation: UnsignedInteger
 Channel Count: 4

32bpp pRGBA (GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPRGBA)
 Guid: 3cc4a650-a527-4d37-a916-3142c7ebedba
 Bits Per Pixel: 32
 Supports Transparency: True
 Numeric Representation: UnsignedInteger
 Channel Count: 4

64bpp RGB (GUID_WICPixelFormat64bppRGB)
 Guid: a1182111-186d-4d42-bc6a-9c8303a8dff9
 Bits Per Pixel: 64
 Supports Transparency: False
 Numeric Representation: UnsignedInteger
 Channel Count: 3

64bpp pRGBA (GUID_WICPixelFormat64bppPRGBA)
 Guid: 6fddc324-4e03-4bfe-b185-3d77768dc917
 Bits Per Pixel: 64
 Supports Transparency: True
 Numeric Representation: UnsignedInteger
 Channel Count: 4

64bpp pRGBA half (GUID_WICPixelFormat64bppPRGBAHalf)
 Guid: 58ad26c2-c623-4d9d-b320-387e49f8c442
 Bits Per Pixel: 64
 Supports Transparency: True
 Numeric Representation: Float
 Channel Count: 4

64bpp RGB half (GUID_WICPixelFormat64bppRGBHalf)
 Guid: 6fddc324-4e03-4bfe-b185-3d77768dc942
 Bits Per Pixel: 64
 Supports Transparency: False
 Numeric Representation: Float
 Channel Count: 3

128bpp pRGBA float (GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppPRGBAFloat)
 Guid: 6fddc324-4e03-4bfe-b185-3d77768dc91a
 Bits Per Pixel: 128
 Supports Transparency: True
 Numeric Representation: Float
 Channel Count: 4

128bpp RGB float (GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppRGBFloat)
 Guid: 6fddc324-4e03-4bfe-b185-3d77768dc91b
 Bits Per Pixel: 128
 Supports Transparency: False
 Numeric Representation: Float
 Channel Count: 3
```

Comment: Here is an official doc to somewhat support this answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct2d/supported-pixel-formats-and-alpha-modes#supported-formats-for-wic-bitmap-render-target